# Converting an edge list to an incidence matrix using in bipartite matrices

Tags: r, matrix, graph, bipartite, edge-list

I have an edge list like this

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
a   2
b   1
```

and I want to build it's incidence matrix which would be like:

```
    a   b   c   d
1   1   1   0   0
2   1   1   0   0
3   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0
```

Any idea to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `factor` and add one more lvl

```
    df=read.table(text='A B
               a   1
               b   2
               c   3
               a   2
               b   1',header=T)

    levels(df$A)=c(levels(df$A),'d')
    df$B=as.factor(df$B)
    levels(df$B)=c(levels(df$B),'4')
    subset=table(df$B,df$A)

> subset

    a   b   c   d
1   1   1   0   0
2   1   1   0   0
3   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Sorry and thank you for your time, but this is an example of a enormous network and is not applicable for large datasets.

Comment: Then can you explain your question a little bit more detail ?

Comment: @minoo [Here](https://solomonmessing.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/working-with-bipartiteaffiliation-network-data-in-r/) is an example of how to build a sparse matrix

Comment: @Wen In my question types of the names of rows and columns are not important, just for each row of the data frame if mat[1,] and mat[,2] for example be in a row so in matrix we put 1 otherwise 0 and expand it for all inputs of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-cbind(df,1)

require(qdapTools)
incidence<-df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df[,'1']), c('A', 'B')] %>%
{split(.[,'B'], .[,'A'])} %>%
  mtabulate()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with xtabs from base stats:

```
a<- data.frame(var1=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b"), var2=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1), stringsAsFactors = F)
b<- as.matrix(xtabs(~var1 +var2, a, sparse = F))
```

If you have also a column weight that you want to use to populate the incidence matrix, I recommend the package EconGeo. The function get.matrix() does the trick wonderfully.